# Did you mean this command instead? (how to reply to this)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command, autocorrection

Suppose I entered the following thing into terminal:

`wgets "link"`

I will get the response:

> No command 'wgets' found, did you mean:
>    Command 'wget' from package 'wget' (main)

I made a mistake, and the terminal warned me.

Is there a command that I can type after the terminal warned me, so that then it will execute the command above with what it thought it was?

For example:

```
->wgets "link"

->No command 'wgets' found, did you mean:
 Command 'wget' from package 'wget' (main)

->yes (this command I am looking for ... is there one?)

-> executing wget "link"
```

Comment: This is not a generic "shell" question.  What happens in this circumstance varies from shell to shell.  The Z shell differing from the Bourne Again shell differing from the Korn shell, for example.  It also depends from what shell extensions are installed.  Your question is describing the behaviour of a particular shell with a particular extension.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of Linux, so feel free to remove tags you don't think are valid here

Comment: In most cases, people take advantage of the respective shells history file here.  Use the Up Arrow to type a repeat of the command, remove the mistake, and continue

Comment: @eyoung100 I'm aware of that, that's why I've been doing until now :P

Comment: Great AFAIK, there is no way to invoke what your asking, as the code in question is part of your `/etc/bashrc` file and as @JdeBP point's out, it would be shell dependent.  Save this for after you earn some reputation, and post your first bounty.  That will get you a badge.

Comment: I think you want [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck).  ;)  I wouldn't use it in Production in a million years, but it's funny.

Comment: @Wildcard LOOOL alright ill check it out

Comment: You're seeing command-not-found output.

Comment: The easy and faster way I know to replace the command is typing: ^gets^get^ and press enter. Bash automatically will call last command and modify wgets for wget and run it.

Comment: @tntx I always wonder how posts from almost 1.5 years ago show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (installed by default on macOS and available as a package on all major Linux distributions, *BSD, and software collections for other Unix-like operating systems). It has autocorrect for command names.

```
% wgets
zsh: correct 'wgets' to 'wget' [nyae]? y
wget: missing URL
…
```

Answer (score 4):

In `Bash` you can use `search and replace` to modify the previously run incorrect command.  From your example:

```
->wgets "link"

->No command 'wgets' found, did you mean:
 Command 'wget' from package 'wget' (main)

->^wgets^wget^
```

The `wgets` will be replaced with `wget` and the command executed.

To facilitate this on a command from earlier in the history list:

```
->!wgets:s/wgets/wget/
```

From `man 3 history` under `Event Designators`:

```
!string
     Refer to the most recent command starting with string.

...

^string1^string2^
     Quick Substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing string1
     with string2.  Equivalent to ''!!:s/string1/string2/''.
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/135943/wildcard) already suggested install [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) and then alias "yes" to it by adding the following lines to your .bash_profile, .bashrc or .zshrc:

```
eval $(thefuck --alias)
alias yes="fuck"
```

```sh
->wgets "link"

->No command 'wgets' found, did you mean:
 Command 'wget' from package 'wget' (main)

->yes

-> wget "link" [enter/↑/↓/ctrl+c]

-> Downloading...
```